# pass data and link attribute to new div

Tags: jquery

This is part 2 to my previous question..  Here is the markup:

html

```
<a data-message="my message" href="www.site.com">click here</a>

<div class="new-window">
    <p>(my message)</p>
    <a href="LINK-GOES-HERE">proceed</a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('a[data-message]').click(function(){
    $('.new-window').fadeIn(300);
    $('.new-window p').text($(this).data('message'));
    return false;
});
```

Since there are a few links on the page, and I want a custom div window (as opposed to a standard alert) to show with a message and url passed to new-window.  Is there a way to pass the selected link's URL to the new window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
$('.new-window p').text($(this).data('message'));
```

Add:

```
$('.new-window a').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.new-window p').text( this.href );
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help:

```
$('a[data-message]').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));
        $('.new-window').fadeIn(300);
        $('.new-window p').text($(this).data('message'));
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Aside from the `console.log` what else did you change from the OP's code?